# VS Code and GifHub downloads 800MB of some data each time I start computer

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-desktop

Every time I start my computer VS Code and GitHub desktop download and send some data. Till this process is not finished, my internet works slow.

What can it be? Is that some software bug or maybe a virus?

My computer is Macbook Pro with macOS Monterey. I noticed that problem a few weeks ago and thought there was some issue with my internet provider until I looked into network activities.

[image]

Comment: Probably an update. These electron apps and for Vscode also it's list of extensions get huge and each can be a substantial download.

Comment: @jessenhouwing each day new update at morning and evening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some updates tried to self-download without success all the time. I downloaded it manually, and the issue was resolved.